# Pass data from UIViewControllerRepresentable to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, swiftui, uikit

I have a UIViewControllerRepresentable like this:

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel    
typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
    
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
         
    // ...
    return viewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIKitInboxDetail, context: Context) {
    // ...
}
```

Inside my viewController there is a collectionView.

Now I would like to detect if my collectionView is scrolled and if so perform some actions.

So i've added this method to my ViewController:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

if let collectionView = scrollView as? UICollectionView {
    isFirstCollectionViewScrolled = true
}
}
```

But i can access this data only when the view is updated and not at run tiem.

Another approach i've tried is the Coordinator, but I cant perform what I want. Any advice?

Recap: I need to perform some action in my SwiftUI View when a scroll is detected.

- - 

Update:

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject { }
```

And in my viewController i'm just implementing the usual CollectionView delegates.

If i print somethng in the metod ScrollViewDidEndDegelerating it works! I just neet do something in my swiftUI View when this happened! (A boolean maybe is not the best approach since it set it to true and then it stay true)

Comment: Create ObservableObject view model with `isFirstCollectionViewScrolled` property and pass that instance into representable and next to internal controller. So you can modify that property in UIKit controller, but still observe/react in SwiftUI view.

Comment: Mmm I have an idea of what u are saying, could you provide some code too please? I think is not a good idea to set a bool as true when scrolled because I need to perform stuff if scrolling

Comment: I could, but I need your code to demo where to inject my. Would you elaborate on providing some minimal testable example?

Comment: Updated my question! Actually there are some usual function, you dont need to test 100% your code , i just need the input! =D